# Loading all mp3's into a audio array

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to load all .mp3 file's from the menusound map into a

```
public AudioClip[] menuSound;
```

Is it possible to locate all .mp3's in a folder and load all them into a `Audioclip[]`?

I know you can separately load all sound tracks but when I try

```
AudioClip[] menuSound = {
    Resources.Load("Gamegeluiden/MenuSounds/menuselect") as AudioClip
};
```

I can only seem to get 1 song into the sound array

```
AudioClip[] menuSound = {Resources.Load("Gamegeluiden/MenuSounds/menuselect") as AudioClip,Resources.Load("Gamegeluiden/MenuSounds/menuselect2") as AudioClip
    };
```

If i try to excess the array after doing this it says 0 = okay  1 = out of range

Comment: Are all audio clips in this directory? Gamegeluiden/MenuSounds/menuselect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your 2nd sound actually exists?  Because the following test code works just fine (in that it plays the 3rd sound in my array):

```
public class SoundLoader : MonoBehaviour {
public AudioClip[] menuSound;
void Start () {
    menuSound = new AudioClip[]{
        Resources.Load("sound1") as AudioClip,
        Resources.Load("sound2") as AudioClip,
        Resources.Load("sound3") as AudioClip
    };
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(menuSound[2],Vector3.zero);
}
}
```

And my current **Project Hierarchy**:

> Assets\
> Assets\Resources\
> Assets\Resources\Sound1
> Assets\Resources\Sound2
> Assets\Resources\Sound3